# Using Makao to analysis glib system

Tags: unix, makefile

I meet some question when I use Makao() as the tutorial(http://mcis.polymtl.ca/makao.html) to analyze the glib system from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/glib/2.49/ .When I get the trace.txt with  `$MAKAO/parsing/bin/makewrapper.sh all 2&> trace.txt`, there is something wrong with it. the trace.txt looks like this:

```
+zsh:1> make -w '--debug=v' '--debug=m' -p 'SHELL:= /bin/zsh -o xtrace' all-recursive
+zsh:1> make -w '--debug=v' '--debug=m' -p 'SHELL:= /bin/zsh -o xtrace' all-recursive
+zsh:1> fail='' 
+zsh:1> fail='' 
+zsh:1> target_option=k 
+zsh:1> target_option=k 
+zsh:1> case k (?)
+zsh:1> case k (?)
```

then I run

```
$MAKAO/parsing/bin/generate_makao_graph.pl -in trace.txt -out trace.gdf \-format gdf
```

the error is like this:

> Cannot parse the following input on line 1: +zsh:1> make -w
>   '--debug=v' '--debug=m' -p 'SHELL:= /bin/zsh -o xtrace' all-recursive,
>   stopped at /Users/caopeng/makao/parsing/bin/generate_makao_graph.pl
>   line 176,  line 1.

I really need some help :( What's wrong with it!

Comment: Apparently it's because you set the `SHELL` to `/bin/zsh -o xtrace'` and MAKAO is parsing the output and gets confused.  Why do you want to do that in the first place?